# How can I add 2 website in one solution

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, file-upload

I have two separate websites in visual-studio-2010. first of all I want to know how can i put these two web projects in one solution and second i have a form in project 1 that tries to add a photo in a folder of project 2  ,how can i do this .

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs("~/project2/Image/" + FileUpload1.FileName.ToString());
```

I've tried this code but it didn't work.

Comment: With regard to your second question: You can also use the complete path to the image folder on the "project 2". For example `FileUpload1.SaveAs(@"C:\project2\Image\" + FileUpload1.FileName.ToString());`

Comment: thanks for your help, but i have to upload this website on my host

Comment: My answer still holds true for your scenario. See answer below.

Comment: @heliaHosseinioun Welcome to StackOverflow. [سلام هلیا جان، به بزرگترین جامعه برنامه نویسان دنیا خوش اومدی]. When you feel you have got the right answer you can accept it [I mentioned this because your other question is also unanswered and I thought maybe you are not aware], and Seany84's answer is exactly your solution.

Comment: @mahditahsildari: thanks mahdi ,But as you said my second question is unanswered yet!

Comment: @heliaHosseinioun You are only meant to ask one question at a time!
I have added an update in the comment of my answer.

Comment: @Seany84 :I'm new in stack overflow and i didn't know the rule but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is two questions. You should really create two separate questions on StackOverflow instead of putting them into one.

### Question 1

Regarding two projects in one solution:

- In Solution Explorer, select the solution.
- On the File menu, point to Add Project, and click Existing Project.
- The Add Existing Project dialog box is displayed.
- Locate the project you want to add, and select the project file.
- Click Open.
- The project is added to the selected solution.

### Question 2

Regarding the second question - If your site is deployed in your local IIS then you could create a virtual directory in both IIS instances that share a common local path.

Comment: could you explain me more about your answer ?i don't know how to do what you said

Comment: @heliaHosseinioun Here is a Microsoft Knowledge base article on the second answer I provided on How to create a virtual directory in IIS: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172138